# Java8 : How Stream works?

Tags: dictionary, foreach, filter, java-8, java-stream

I am studying Java8 esp Stream API.
but still don't get it how stream and map work.

what i understood of stream was like
the result will be 1111 2222 when i use peek() and forEach() but the result of println() is mixed.

i thought if i use map().filter().map().filter() then first of all do first map() and return to stream and do next filter() and moving to next like this. so i am so confused of this result.

this is my code

```
package exam_20170823;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;

    public class StreamEx2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    File[] fileArr = {
            new File("Ex1.java"),
            new File("Ex1.bak"),
            new File("Ex1.txt"),
            new File("Ex2.java"),
            new File("Ex1")

    };


    /*1) make stream
      2) find filename extension
      3) change 2) to uppercase
      4) remove duplicate
      5) print
    */

    Stream<File> fileStream = Stream.of(fileArr);

    fileStream.map(s->s.getName())
                .filter(s -> s.indexOf(".") != -1)
                .peek(a -> System.out.println(a))
                .map(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf(".")+1).toUpperCase())
                .distinct()  
                .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));


}
```

}

and this is result

`Ex1.java
JAVA
Ex1.bak
BAK
Ex1.txt
TXT
Ex2.java`

just i want to know why the result is not like this? -> "Ex1.java,Ex1.bak,Ex1.txt,Ex2.java" first, and print "JAVA,BAK,TXT"
i used peek() first and finally use foreach() so i expected 
after using peek() the stream will be `Ex1.java,Ex1.bak,Ex1.txt,Ex2.java` 
and then next i use map() so it must have `JAVA,BAK,TXT`. and 
finally use foreach() so each things of stream will be printed what was what i expected but it is so confused. is anyone can help me to understand why?

Comment: where do you see `1111` and `2222` ???

Comment: not literally i see 1111 2222 just i meant order of output :)

Comment: The order of the output looks fine. If something is not clear to you, please be more specific and accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing laziness here. Not *all* elements are going to go through the `map`, then *all to the* `filter` and then all that are filtered going to the other `map`. This is not how stream works.

The processing is **lazy**. Meaning that one element at a time is taken from the `source` (in your case an array of `File`s), then that element goes through all of the stages of the Stream pipeline (`map`, then `filter`, then `peek`); notice that if `filter` fails, it does not reaches `peek` at all. Then the second element is taken from the source and does the same thing and so on.

That is why you see the output on each stage at a time. See this example:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
            .filter(x -> {
                System.out.println("Filering x = " + x);
                return x > 2;
            })
            .map(x -> {
                System.out.println("Mapping x = " + x);
                return x + 1;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Notice how the `mapping` stage is being executed only at the third element, because the first two do not satisfy the `Predicate` in the `filter` stage.

Comment: Your explanation and this example really helped me to understand how laziness works. Thank you alot!